# How quickly does water lose heat by thermal radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, thermal-radiation

Let's say I hold in space room-temperature water, shadowed so no radiation is emitted onto it and surrounded by vacuum (let's assume it won't boil even with the low pressure). I assume the surface area matters, so let's say the shape of water is of a thin layer.

How quickly would heat escape the water? How example going from 20° Celsius to 0° Celsius?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this might be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity

Comment: @Solomon Slow Yeah, I tried reading that earlier but I didn't find a simple answer in there.

Comment: Don't assume it won't boil in a vacuum, because it will -- at the same time it's freezing from evaporative heat loss.  Rather, invoke Physics Magic and say that it's confined within an infinitely strong, perfectly transparent container.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not simple. Thus, I do not have an answer, but I’ll point you in the right direction. Here are the steps to get an estimate; hopefully I haven’t forgotten anything. Let’s be real, I probably forgot something. In any case, pay attention to your units so you don’t screw something up.

1. Look up the water absorptivity spectrum (=emissivity spectrum).
2. Assume you have enough water the it is optically “thick” for all the emission wavelengths and multiply by the black body emission spectrum at 20 $^\circ$C.
3. Assume that the black body emission spectrum is constant over your temperature range of interest, integrate over wavelength, surface area, and 4$\pi$ steradians, and obtain the total power emission rate.
4. Look up the heat capacity of water and assume it is constant over your temperature range of interest (definitely not true when crossing a phase transition). So redefine your problem so you’re asking only about a 1 $^\circ$C change.
5. Multiply your energy rate of change by heat capacity to solve for temperature rate of change, per volume.
6. Plug in the size of your water blob and desired temperature difference to solve for time.
7. Crack open a beer and celebrate: You’ve estimated something rather silly and unphysical, but interesting nonetheless?

Comment: Plenty of steps! I'll gather the data and try arriving at a result later.

Comment: "Assume ... optically 'thick'".  Then double check just how thick a blob you'll need.  If you're thinking about a volume of water similar to an orange, or even an average bedroom, you'll probably want to determine the _effective_ emissivity of the blob will be given its size.  Start by searching on "extinction coefficient", maybe add "of water" to that, then just follow the rabbit-hole until you surface again.  Come to think of it, if it's a planet-sized blob you can just assume it's opaque -- so in this case, size does matter.

Comment: Step 3 is interesting, as the total emission is proportional to T$^4$.

Comment: @my2cts, yeah the step 3 assumption would give a ~30% error for the 20 C to 0 C range in the question. So if we conclude that that’s the dominant error, then you’re right, we can do better.